# Counterexample for Trace operator in BV space.

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, bounded-variation

Suppose $\Omega\subset R^N$ is open bounded with Lipschitz boundary. Then for $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, there exists a linear operator $T$: $W^{1,p}(\Omega)\to L^{p}(\partial\Omega)$ such that the integration by parts formula will hold. And in addition, we have
$$ \|T[u]\|_{L^p}\leq C\|u\|_{W^{1,p}}$$
This is the common result and we can find the prove in Evans & Gapriep book for example.

Now let us move to $BV(\Omega)$. We can also define the same trace operator and hence the integration by parts formula will work. However, I am really interested in the question that whether we have
$$ \|T[u]\|_{L^1}\leq C\|u\|_{BV(\Omega)}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$
Is inequality $(1)$ hold? Yes, from the comment below by @John we just need to notice that $T$ is actually an linear BOUNDED operator.

Moreover, for same $\Omega$, we can approach $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ by a sequence $(u_n)\subset C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$ in the norm of $W^{1,p}$ for $p<\infty$. Now, for $BV(\Omega)$, can we have $(u_n)\subset C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$ such that $u_n\to u$ in $L^1$ and $\|Du_n\|(\Omega)\to \|Du\|(\Omega)$? Again, I don't think so, but could you help me to come up a counterexample?  (Certainly $u\in BV(\Omega)$ can be approximated by $(u_n)\subset C^\infty({\Omega})$)

Thx!

Update: Now I have a prove for my second question. It is true actually. The way to prove this is to using extension operator $E$ and noticing the fact that $\|\partial E[u]\|(\partial \Omega)=0$

Comment: The first assertion can be found in "Measure theory and fine properties of measure" by Evans (again!) and Gapriepy, Chapter 5. For your second assertion, please see 5.2.2 for a similar statments

Comment: Please, I am studying this book but I can not find it. For my first question, Evans & Gapriepy does not have an answer. In their prove and theorem they mention nothing about the estimation in $BV$ trace. And for my second question, they only have the answer for the case $u_n\in C^\infty(\Omega)$ but not for $u_n\in C^\infty(\bar{\Omega})$

Comment: oh sorry, I wrote Evans in my post, I actually mean Evans & Gapriepy... Will change it.

Comment: For the first one (inequality (1)), isn't that Theorem 5.3.1 in the book?

Comment: Oh sorry I just understand it! they assert that $T$ is an linear BOUNDED map from $BV(\Omega)\to L^1(\partial \Omega)$ so necessarily we have $\|T[u]\|_{L^1(\partial \Omega)}\leq \|T\|\|u\|_{BV(\Omega)}$!!

Comment: Sorry I was just focusing on finding this estimation in their prove but forgot this part... clearly, in Sobolev case they have this estimation right in their prove but not for BV case... Thx! Now what do you think about my second question?

Comment: That's a nice question. I guess it can be done using similar techniques in the book..... I will try to prove that if I have time......

Comment: Thx! I was trying to use Theorem 3 in page 127 to prove it. But, you will see, it is not very straightforward....

Comment: I think I have a prove. I will update my post tonight